# If two matrices are similar, then is it true that their transposes are similar?

Tags: linear-algebra

Taken from a previously answered question on matrix similarities:

Similar matrices share many properties:

- Rank
- Determinant
- Trace
- Eigenvalues (though the eigenvectors will in general be different)
- Characteristic polynomial
- Minimal polynomial (among the other similarity invariants in the Smith normal form)
- Elementary divisors

What I'm wondering is if this implies that the transposes will be similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $$ P^{-1} A P = B, $$
$$ P^T A^T \left( P^{-1} \right)^T = B^T  $$

Just to be sure,
$$ I = I^T = \left( P P^{-1} \right)^T = \left( P^{-1} \right)^T P^T. $$
This means that, once $P$ is invertible, so is $P^T,$ and
$$ \left( P^{-1} \right)^T = \left( P^T \right)^{-1}. $$